# Why won't my macbook show the dashboard or fullscreen windows?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, bug, fullscreen, dashboard

I am "stuck" on the desktop. Clicking the dashboard icon does nothing, I cannot use the 4-finger swipe gestures to move to or view the dashboard or any application windows in fullscreen (yes, I have checked system preferences, it's on), and the function key that usually allows me to see fullscreen windows+the dashboard+other desktops does nothing. I have tried shutting my computer, quitting everything and restarting. If I open another fullscreen window, I am stuck there until I close or un-maximize it. This has happened before and it went away after a minute or two, but it's sticking around now. I have a MacBook Air running on Mac OS El Capitan.

How can I solve/prevent this problem?

UPDATE: It has started working again, but was stuck for much longer this time.

This problem is continuing off and on.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have too many junk files
here is what to do:
1.Delete Files you no longer need.
2.Empty Trash. Having too much junk slows down your laptop
3.Install A program that cleans your laptop

Or maybe there is a virus installed in your computer
here is what you have to do:
1.Move the file you think may be causing the bug.
2.Install MacKeeper
3.Run MacKeeper and scan your pc for viruses
4.If the app found a virus delete it

so thats it thanks!

Comment: Other people had mixed experiences with MacKeeper (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=mackeeper), I would probably analyze the issue in more details before suspecting a virus here.